# Determining File Type from Extension

Tags: java, file-extension

Is there a simple way in Java to translate file extensions to specific file types? That is, I'd like to translate ".doc" to "Microsoft Word Document." But I also do NOT want to look inside each file to determine mime type etc because of the performance hit that entails.

Is there a library or database file listing all the currently accepted extensions and their meanings? Something I can load programmatically and then search when I need to?

Comment: Depends on the operating system. On Windows, you can probably just read the registry.

Comment: Or you can try scraping this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats)

Comment: to my knowledge, there is no such database. compiling one would be a pretty hard task, as people invent or mis-use extensions all the time, commercially and otherwise. I'd suggest you use your own database with the ones you care about. :)

Comment: I have the feeling this is a **XY question**. What exactly do you need this for? What does it help you to know that `.doc` is `Microsoft Word Document`? Do you just want to display some sort of description? Or do you also need to know the program the user associated to this extension (that might be different for every user)?

Comment: On Windows you can also try the result of the [`assoc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) command (should be a *summary* of registry data) e.g. `assoc .doc` returns `.doc=Word.Document.8`. `assoc` without arguments list all known extensions

Comment: I'm constructing a file browser and just want to list files and their types. Hoping to do it in a platform-independent fashion, though I'm open to platform-dependent solutions (Windows & MACOS). I'm also hoping to avoid having to import/massage a bunch of extension data myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft [has a support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/common-file-name-extensions-in-windows-da4a4430-8e76-89c5-59f7-1cdbbc75cb01) on common file name extensions.

The wikipedia page on '[list of file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats)' seems pretty exhaustive.

It should be easy to copy / paste one (or both) of those lists, tweak the formatting with a text editor, and push it into your code via a hard-coded array or external resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind that if you go this route then you are trusting that the files contain the type of data that the extension claims. This is going to be a somewhat brittle solution because it will only take one upstream error to break things.

Much better IMO is to read the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) (ie. file signature) from the first handful of bytes in the file itself. Just about any production or commercial software will do this (at an absolute minimum) instead of trusting the file extension. It would still be possible for a malicious user to fake the signature, but that requires intentional action and not just a coding error.

The cost of doing this versus checking the extension is really not substantially different; unless you are processing an enormous number of files or have some super tight deadlines (and in that case, Java might not be the best choice), both approaches require not much beyond asking the OS to read a handful of bytes from disk. Checking the magic numbers will just require a few more bytes to be read, and the overhead of opening/closing a stream on each file.

Comment: I understand there'll be trust that files are what their extensions make them out to be. But the file browser I'm working on could have lots of files in a given folder -- I'm looking at one right now that's got 15,000+. Actually opening and reading even just a few bytes from that many files is a major task. And then I still have to translate to human-readable file types.

Comment: If you are sure that the extensions will either be valid or that your program will be able to correctly handle mislabeled files, then the other answers/comments are probably the way to go. It might be a good idea to try coding it both ways and compare the runtime of both. That way you'll have some empirical data to help quantify the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, those names are only available in the registry.  I’ve seen attempts to use Swing’s FileView to get them, but I wouldn’t rely on that, especially for headless code.

```
public static String getFullFileTypeName(String extension)
throws IOException,
       InterruptedException {

    if (!extension.startsWith(".")) {
        extension = "." + extension;
    }

    String progID = readDefaultValue(extension);
    String name = readDefaultValue(progID);

    return name;
}

private static String readDefaultValue(String node)
throws IOException,
       InterruptedException {

    String registryPath = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\" + node;
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
        "reg.exe", "query", registryPath, "/ve");
    builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

    String value = null;
    Process process = builder.start();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int regSZIndex = line.indexOf("REG_SZ");
            if (regSZIndex >= 0) {
                value = line.substring(regSZIndex + 6).trim();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Consume remaining output.
        if (line != null) {
            int c;
            do {
                c = reader.read();
            } while (c >= 0);
            // As of Java 11, the above loop can be replaced with:
            //reader.transferTo(Writer.nullWriter());
        }
    }

    int returnCode = process.waitFor();
    if (returnCode != 0) {
        throw new IOException("Got return code " + returnCode
            + " from " + builder.command());
    }

    if (value == null) {
        throw new IOException(
            "Could not find value for \"" + registryPath + "\"");
    }

    return value;
}
```